# Using a PHP (or JS) script to click an external button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to write a PHP script which,  when run, sets the values of the drop down menus on the page [here](http://voyager.gsfc.nasa.gov/heliopause/recenthist.html) and then submits these values by pressing the 'Fetch Button'.

This should link to another page (http://voyager.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/heliopause_all), the contents of which I would like the PHP script to return.

I have not attempted this, since I have very limited PHP knowledge, so I ask whether this would be possible and what I would have to learn about PHP to do this?

### -- Edit --

Looking at the source code, would this be possible with simply a POST request from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea I have had.
Make a POST with curl to: http://voyager.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/heliopause_all

with these POST-Parameters

```
average:6hour
syear:9999
smonth:9999
sday:9999
eyear:9999
emonth:9999
eday:9999
sat:1
mnemonic:IPGH
duration:3-months
outputType:list
timeFormat:ISO
```

The last step is to parse the response.

Code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://voyager.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/heliopause_all';
$parameters_str = '';
$parameters = array(
    'average'=>'6hour',
    'syear'=>'9999',
    'smonth'=>'9999',
    'sday'=>'9999',
    'eyear'=>'9999',
    'emonth'=>'9999',
    'eday'=>'9999',
    'sat'=>'1',
    'mnemonic'=>'IPGH',
    'duration'=>'3-months',
    'outputType'=>'list',
    'timeFormat'=>'ISO'
);

foreach ($parameters as $k => $v) {
    $parameters_str .= $k . '=' . $v . '&';
}
rtrim($parameters_str, '&');


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($parameters));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant. Just need somewhere to host it now :D